# Hyper-V Connect

Tags: windows, hyper-v, desktop

i am installed Windows 2008 OS and on that i installed Hyper-v. i am using Windows XP desktop. By using this desktop is it possibul to connect Hyper-V. if possibul please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think administration requires Vista - for the admin tools to be installed. That said, you can always Remote desktop into the server and manage locally (which is what i do - my normal company logon has no admin rights on hyper-v).